# typescript autocomplete for mocha, chai and cy outside cypress folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, visual-studio-code, cypress

I'm trying to config `cypress` and `typescript` to allow run tests on the same folder of my project instead of the default `integrations` folder.

I made it works running the tests, but I just cannot find a way to allow the `mocha`,  `chai` and `cy` autocomplete work on the test file, it keep trying to get the default `jest` config from CRA.

I tried to remove `jest` ejecting the project but it don't work, the only thing I got was the `describe`, `it`, `cy` and `expect` to be like `any`.

The stranger thing was that sometimes, I didn't know why, it gets the right config, after so much debugging I realize that if I change something inside `/cypress/plugins` or `/cypress/support` the autocomplete start to work, but it's lost when I restart `vscode`.

With that behavior I start to think that `vscode` initially don't get the `tsconfig.json` inside `cypress` folder. Since nothing makes reference to that file/folder it makes sense, make even more sense knowing that when I save something inside that two folders above the autocomplete start to work.

But I still don't know what to do to allow autocomplete without needing to change something inside `/cypress` every session. Does someone know how can I make this work?

I add that config on `cypress.json`

```json
{
  "integrationFolder": "./src",
  "testFiles": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx"
  ]
}
```

my root `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx"
  ]
}
```

and the cypress `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/cypress",
    "../src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../src/**/*.spec.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

Comment: I use TypeScript and Cypress together in one of my projects and it does have autocomplete support. I think you probably miss this? `"types": ["cypress"]` in your cypress' __tsconfig.json__

Comment: I try this, but add `"types": ["cypress"]` to root tsconfig on CRA only leads to a unfixable bug that all files must be modules. I kind of find a way to solve this creating another tsconfig file inside `/src`, it isn't the best approach, but does the trick.

Comment: If you did solve the problem, you can answer you own question and mark it as accepted to close this question and it might help people facing the same problem in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so many tries I figure out a way good approach. As I described [here](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test/issues/372) my biggest mistake was add the `exclude` to the root `tsconfig.json`, removing them I can create a `tsconfig.cypress.json` on the project root alongside `tsconfig.json` with that work as expected.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "types": ["cypress"],
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.cypress.json`

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "noEmit": false,
    "baseUrl": "./node_modules"
  },
  "include": [
    "./node_modules/cypress",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx"
  ],
}
```

I have only one point that I cant figure out that was the need of `"types": ["cypress"]` on the root `tsconfig`, if I define it on `tsconfig.cypress.json` the typing don't work, however that's a minimal detail.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Your note helped me: I just needed to add `cypress` to the `types` list in my root tsconfig.